# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, cordova, frameworks, linker-errors

I have added a custom plugin to Cordova app. And the custom plugin uses a third party framework.
When i build it through cordova command line the build fails with the error

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
```

But if i open xcode project now and build the app its working fine and that framework is alos added in the embedded bianries in Xcode. But i want to buil the app from cordova command line as  it needs to be automated as a part of build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error is “clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1“**

You can add the deployment-target preference to your project's config.xml. For example, this would set the deployment target to iOS 10.0.

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="11.0" />
```

Comment: explaining how to open this would be more meaningful , no meaning for the above answer

Answer (score -10):

Clean and rebuild the project.